# Problem Current Date Plus One Hour Android

Tags: android, datetime

I have a problem when I try to get the current datetime on my android emulator.
Actually on my emulator are the 12:25 (GMT+1) and if I get the time using this code:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

I get:

```
Thu Feb 10 12:25:18 GMT+01:00 2022
```

Which is right.
But if I do it with ISO timeformat, so:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

I get:

```
Thu Feb 10 01:25:18 GMT+01:00 2022
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Is it just me or does do both outputs look nothing like the format you passed...? Did you shuffle it around to make them look uniform or what?

Comment: I got it from the debugger and they are show in that way xD So I didn't modify them

Comment: Well that's weird because the formats you provided start with "yyyy" and "dd/MM" etc, so "Thu Feb" shouldn't be the output of either of them. What are you looking at in the debugger, maybe something else?

Comment: No I'm looking at the variable I set to get the time